Databricks DLT Streaming Schema
I am trying to create a delta live table from a JSON message that has two arrays [NewData, OldData]. I pass my schema in the readStream code and select only NewData.* to get the fields in the NewData array. However, I notice that the table ends up creating the columns for the NewData and OldData, and the NewData fields.



NewData
OldData
NewData_Field1
NewData_Field2
...




Null
Null
1
2
...



Is there a way to only get the NewData records in my delta live streaming table?
Code below.
schema = StructType([
    StructField("NewData", StructType([
        StructField(...
    ]), True),
    StructField("OldData", StructType([
        StructField(...


@dlt.table(
    name="newdata_raw",
    table_properties={"quality": "bronze"},
    temporary=False,
)
def create_table():
    query = (
        spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
        .schema(schema)
        .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
        .option("checkpointLocation", sink_dir +"checkpoint/")
        .load(sink_dir)
        .select("NewData.*")
        .withColumn("load_date", to_timestamp(current_timestamp()))
    )
    return query


Solved: I ended up needing to do a full refresh on the table. Since it initially ran without the select statement the two top-level arrays were created and then stayed on subsequent runs.
